# Ошибка при инициализации компонента

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Почему VS2015 не может проинициализировать компонент scintillanet в designer после переноса программы на другой пк?

1. VS2015 абсолютно одинаковая
2. Добавления библиотеки производилось точно также как и на первом пк
3. версия scintillanet та же

> Вот ошибка:

**The designer cannot process the code at line 6315, please see the Task List for details. The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again**

> Это код line 6315

```
        this.scintilla1.SearchFlags = ((ScintillaNET.SearchFlags)((((ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.WholeWord | ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.MatchCase)
        | ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.WordStart)
        | ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.RegExp)));
```

> Это конфигурация всего компонента

```
        this.scintilla1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Language = "mssql";
        this.scintilla1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 219);
        this.scintilla1.Margins.Margin0.Width = 20;
        this.scintilla1.Name = "scintilla1";
        this.scintilla1.SearchFlags = ((ScintillaNET.SearchFlags)((((ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.WholeWord | ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.MatchCase)
        | ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.WordStart)
        | ScintillaNET.SearchFlags.RegExp)));
        this.scintilla1.Styles.BraceBad.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.BraceLight.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.CallTip.FontName = "Segoe UI\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.ControlChar.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.Default.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        this.scintilla1.Styles.Default.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.IndentGuide.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.LastPredefined.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.LineNumber.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.Styles.Max.FontName = "Verdana\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        this.scintilla1.TabIndex = 15;
        this.scintilla1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.scintilla1_TextChanged);
        this.scintilla1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.scintilla1_Enter_1)
```

Comment: От `line 6315` у меня мурашки по коже.

Comment: Это только часть программы, обязательно скину ссылку как доделаю

Comment: `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` -- это для чего? обязательно?

Comment: это  коды стилей текста , к ним претензий не может быть, там все статично

Comment: ну как бы у вас в ошибке же написано, "руками не трогать". Типа убейте все что написали ручками и попробуйте открыть дизайнер вновь. Дизайнер в студии, да еще и для XAML это просто песня, руки бы оторвать тому кто его написал :)

Comment: да и вообще, у вас ошибка может быть вовсе не там где ищете, например если переносили проект ручками, а не через TFS к примеру.